# How can I perform/run Initial Pipeline from Groovy based Job DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a trouble about running initial pipeline from Job Dsl. **Is there way to perform/run initial pipeline automatically after it is created.** I am creating dynamic pipeline for each feature branch. So In each time when the feature pipeline created, I want to run it automatically after pipeline and its job creation completed.I don't want to perform pipeline manually from Jenkins. Because it is too tricky to perform each created feature pipeline.

Comment: Are you using Jenkins pipelines or [Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin)?

Comment: I am using Job DSL plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `queue` to schedule a build of a job. See https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands#queue

```
pipelineJob('example') {
  // ...
}

queue('example')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I also discussed with my architecture level colleagues and they also proposed me to use queue and it actually works and what i exactly looking for solution.

Comment: Can you use queue to only execute "scan multibranch pipeline" instead of actually running the job?